# Labeling a 2D feature layer in ArcGIS javascript API 4.x

Tags: arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm in the process of updating my application from ArcGIS JS API3.x to 4.7. I'm unable to add labeling to a feature class. As per ESRI, they support labeling only for 3D or a MapImage layer in 2D. In 3.X i was able to add a label class to a feature layer to show the labels.

Is there a way to add the labels in 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [3.x to 4.x Functionality Matrix](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/functionality-matrix/index.html), if you look under `esri/layers/FeatureLayer > Labeling`, as of current writing (June 2018) it says "Supported in SceneView(3D). ***Coming soon for MapView(2D).***"